# UIWebview get event when video is Played

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube, uiwebview

UIWebview get event when video is Played. I am playing youtube video in UIWebview. Is it possible to get event when a video is played in UIWebview

Answer (score 0):

From Documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference :

you could define some states in your header file

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, YoutubeVideoState){
YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_UNSTARTED   = -1,
YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_ENDED       = 0,
YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_PLAYING     = 1,
YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_PAUSED      = 2,
YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_BUFFERING   = 3,
YOUTUBE_VIDEO_STATE_VIDEO_CUED  = 5
```

};

Again define random `property` in header file to get the state.

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) YoutubeVideoState state;
```

and implement like :

```
- (YoutubeVideoState)state
{
    return (YoutubeVideoState)[[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"getPlayerState()"] integerValue];
}
```

Then do like this:

```
if(event.data==YT.PlayerState.PLAYING){ 
//do here what do you want
                }
```

Google has provide a library to embedding you tube into iOS.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Comment: Where will I get this "YT.PlayerState.PLAYING" in Objective C. Can you please explain it.

Comment: You need to use java script for that